Why we can't switch the bounds of $\theta$ and $\phi$ in spherical coordinates?
I noticed that $r^2 \sin(\theta)drd\theta d\phi$ doesn't give the same value when integrated:

for $\theta$ from $0$ to $\pi$ and $\phi$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ (the traditional way)
for $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ and $\phi$ from $0$ to $\pi$

For instance if I, in addition, integrate for $r$ from $0$ to $R$, the first one gives the formula of the volume of a sphere, while the second one gives $0$.
I don't really understand this change, since the whole sphere is outlined whether we take $\theta$ from $0$ to $\pi$ and $\phi$ from $0$ to $2\pi$, or $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ and $\phi$ from $0$ to $\pi$.
I understand how to derive the $$r^2 \sin(\theta)drd\theta d\phi = dr\times rd\theta \times r\sin(\theta) d\phi$$ formula.
And I don't understand how the way of deriving the $r^2 \sin(\theta)drd\theta d\phi $ could be affected by switching $\theta$ from $0$ to $\pi$ and $\phi$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ to $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ and $\phi$ from $0$ to $\pi$.

This is probably better asked to Mathematics.

This is because $r^2 \sin\theta$ is the Jacobian of the transformation $(x,y,z) \rightarrow (r, \theta, \phi)$. The Jacobian is the absolute value of the determinant of the matrix $M_{ij} = \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial y_j}$, where $x_i$ are the old coordinates, and $y_i$ are the new coordinates.
Because it is the absolute value of the determinant, it must be non-negative everywhere. We don't have to worry about this using the ordinary coordinates, because $\sin \theta \geq 0$ when $\theta \in [0, \pi]$. However, using your proposed variables, the correct Jacobian would be $r^2 |\sin \theta|$. With this Jacobian, your results would agree.

This is because while volume is always positive, $\sin\theta$ can be negative (from $\pi$ to 2$\pi$ in your specified range).
Basically, what your integral ends up doing is calculating half of the volume of sphere in positive and the other half in negative, so the value of the integral is $0$.
If you take $dV= r^2 |\sin\theta| d\theta d\phi$ and then integrate it with switched limits of $\theta$ and $\phi$, you'd get the correct answer. Alternatively, you can just take limits of $\theta$ from $0$ to $\pi$, since $\sin\theta$ is always positive there and you won't need the absolute value bars.

The representation of a metric manifold consists of an atlas of maps, local flat lattices in copies of $\mathbb R^n$, bound together in an atlas, with overlaps that make navigation  along a path over the boundaries of two neighboring maps possible in a continuous way using a local overlap map.
Our 2-sphere of radius $r$ needs at least two maps. Its topology of paths, the fact, that every closed path can be shrunk to a point, makes if impossible to cover it globally by two nonsingular independent vector fields  representing the two independent directions of movement, degrees of freedom, at all points of sphere.
The natural atlas of the euclidean 2-sphere of radius $r$ in euclidean flat 3-space consísts of the two circular flat maps, flat polar maps around the north and south poles printed on the two sides of a flat paper disk, one map on each side slightly extending over the equator .
On the noth pole map $ r \ \theta$ represents the metric radial coordinate and $r \ \sin \theta \ \phi$ the angular metric coordinate. On the southern hemisphere map replace $\theta$ by $\pi -\theta$.
The two polar maps can be extended up to small circles of a small radius $r_\epsilon$ around the other pole, but at the pole they becom meaningless, because on the other side of the equator the circumference of circles of radius $r\ \theta $ begin to shrink according to $ S\ = \ 2 \ \pi \ r \ \sin \theta$ going to zero at the other pole.
This topological scheme is characteristically for all $n$-spheres: There is a global rotational invariant axis in $\mathbb R^n$ and its complementary set of hyperplanes with rotation angles in $\phi\in (0,2\pi)$ intersecting in the axis. Any point has a position on a hyperplane of angle $\phi$. The other $n-2$ angles $\theta_3,\dots, \theta_n$ all vary only in $(0,\pi)$ along half circles and the metric is becoming singular at both ends, where all meridians meet.
It follows, that all integrals on spheres imply a voluminous set of maps, Jacobians, metric coefficients, directional derivatives and boundaries with special conditions for the coordinate maps to $\mathbb R^n$ used.
In contrast to pure mathmetics, in physics and in theoretical physics the symbols in use have a fixed connection the underlying maps, such that formula lookup is enough in general. The fact that one is using a single map to (not quite) cover the 2-sphere is  historically due to two facts: 1. The integrands are regular at the poles, the volume is zero, no problems. 2. No navigation by compass possible on the earth poles, that relies on the singular magnetic  field.

It is actually weirder for you to think that there is that kind of symmetry.
I mean, it is very good that you know that it came from $r\,\mathrm d\vartheta\times r\sin\vartheta\,\mathrm d\varphi$, such that the angular integration element is $\sin\vartheta\,\mathrm d\vartheta\,\mathrm d\varphi$; look, in this form, it is clear from the presence of $\sin\vartheta$ that the $\vartheta$ coördinate is not the same as the $\varphi$ coördinate.
We can even go further into this analysis. We can make the coördinate swap from $\vartheta$ to $\chi=-\cos\vartheta$ so then $\sin\vartheta\,\mathrm d\vartheta=\mathrm d\chi$ so that we have a symmetric $\mathrm d\chi\,\mathrm d\varphi$. But the difference is even more stark here, since $\chi\in[-1,+1]$ whereas $\varphi\in(-\pi,+\pi]$. Also, you would have that this scheme would have come from $r\frac{\mathrm d\chi}{\sqrt{1-\chi^2}}\times r\sqrt{1-\chi^2}\,\mathrm d\varphi$, so that it is not at all obvious that there is coördinate permutation symmetry.
Amusingly, I kinda prefer having $\varphi\in[0,\pi)$ with $r$ going negative...
